# Update rows for a given condition with select in one EXECUTION: DB2

Tags: select, db2, sql-update

I am trying to update rows with a select on the same table. In my case, I want to update status with 0, if the value of rows occurs more than one in same column.

For example, **item1** occurs three times, that's why I want to change the value of 2 another item1 with status 0.

I tried so far with my code, but I am still struggling for expected result.

```
select * from (
    UPDATE table_1 t1
    SET STATUS = 0 where exists (
    select t1.*, lag(ITEM, 1, 0) over (order by ITEM_1 ASC) as C2
    from table_1 AS t1) 
    WHERE ITEM_1 = C2)
```

```
#|ID| ITEM_1   |STATUS
-+--+---------+------
1|10| item1    |   1       
2|11| item1    |   1  
3|12| item1    |   1  
4| 7| item2    |   1  
5| 2| item3    |   1    
6| 9| item3    |   1     
7|13| item3    |   1      
8|14| item3    |   1
```

expected result.

```
#|ID| ITEM_1   |STATUS
-+--+---------+------+
1|10| item1    |   1  | 
2|11| item1    |   0  | 
3|12| item1    |   0  |
4| 7| item2    |   1  |
5| 2| item3    |   1  |
6| 9| item3    |   0  |  
7|13| item3    |   0  | 
8|14| item3    |   0  |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE
(
  SELECT 
    STATUS
  , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_1 ORDER BY ID) AS RN_
  FROM TABLE_1 T
)
SET STATUS = 0
WHERE RN_ <> 1;

SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 ORDER BY ITEM_1, ID;
```

| ID | ITEM_1 | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | item1 | 1 |
| 11 | item1 | 0 |
| 12 | item1 | 0 |
| 7 | item2 | 1 |
| 2 | item3 | 1 |
| 9 | item3 | 0 |
| 13 | item3 | 0 |
| 14 | item3 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IMMncGId)

**Update**

With a single statement:

```
WITH U AS 
(
  SELECT COUNT (1) AS DUMMY
  FROM NEW TABLE
  (
    UPDATE TABLE_1 A
    SET STATUS = 0
    WHERE EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM TABLE_1 B 
      WHERE B.ITEM_1 = A.ITEM_1 AND A.ID > B.ID
    )
  )
)
SELECT * 
FROM 
--U
TABLE_1
ORDER BY ITEM_1, ID
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Fn6tnayT)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to get the outcome with one time execute. For your given code, I need to execute two-time, first time for update and second time for select.

Comment: What outcome do you want to get exactly? All table contents or just affected rows only?

Comment: All table contents after update.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please, check it.